# How do I render image only without shading

Tags: mesh

I am in cycles and maybe I should only use blender render for what I am after.  I just want it to show the bitmap and if does create shadows I don't want big dots scattered about.
I there a way in cycles to just not put any of the shading dots at all ?
Also what controls the size and number of dots.  ?
It seams I have better results from Material only but It has these lines showing up that I wish would go away.

[image: Using cycles as image only question]ack.imgur.com/mRRsU.jpg

Comment: It should say- and IF cycles DOES add shadows how do I control the size of the dots.

Comment: I don't see any dots... but I do see "lines". If you want to disable the shading lines, then in object mode, under tools in the toolbar, click Shading **smooth**, not **flat**

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that what you were trying to eliminate was the apparent 'lines' in the mesh, and that might actually be a matter of applying 'shade smooth' to the mesh before render. The geometry will show like that if there is no smoothing, regardless of renderer used.

Answer (score 0):

This happends to many Cycle users. The problem is that the texture is too small and gets blurred.

To solve this, use a photo editing software like Gimp or Photoshop. Scale the photo up and apply new texture

For the shadows, try to add a few extra row of pixels to texture on the outside.

Answer (score 0):

As shown by gexwing in the link below, here is a node setup you could try:

[Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUSFh.png)

Source:
https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?244662-Cycles-Getting-rid-of-Texture-Interpolation-yay-for-blocky-no-for-blurry!!!!

Comment: @NeilGilomee please help us make this a better site with in depth answers. Please avoid providing only a link. Try to summarize the information on the link so that your answer stands on its own. The links should be provided as a means to get additional information. Remember that if for any reason the link changes or disappears your answer will make no sense...